# How can I sort and filter a plist data at once?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, plist, filtering

Objective-C newbie here,

I am trying to pull data from a plist, filter it, then sort.
I use the sorting method below on other pages and it works fine.

I do get this alert on the line noted below:
Incompatible pointer types assigning to `'NSMutableArray *'` from `'NSArray *'`

I get this error:

```
2011-12-19 11:16:39.142 ATCScontacts[2511:707] -[__NSArrayI sortUsingDescriptors:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x159cf0
2011-12-19 11:16:39.149 ATCScontacts[2511:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI sortUsingDescriptors:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x159cf0'
```

Interface File:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class customDetailViewController;
@interface contactsViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *contacts_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* contacts;
```

Implementation File:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

//Load plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contactD" ofType:@"plist"];
    contacts_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

//Filter array using predicates
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", "ABC", selection];

//ALERT DISPLAYS HERE:
    contacts_ = [contacts_ filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

//Apply sorting on load
    NSSortDescriptor *contactSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:LAST_KEY ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [contacts_ sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:contactSorter]];

    [contactSorter release];  
}
```

Help help!

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is appearing because, you actually try to assign `NSArray *` to `NSMutableArray`...

To solve this get a mutable copy of the array like so :

```
[[contacts_ filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

But you still got a memory issue, a proper way would be :

```
NSArray *tmp = [contacts_ filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
[contacts_ removeAllObjects];
[contacts_ addObjectsFromArray:tmp];
```